# Load div remotely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Below I have two divs. Div "one" is loaded with an image directly.
How can I load an image 'remotely' using script, that's basically saying 'Load this image into div two'? This image has to be loaded behind the text.

```css
.text1 {
  margin: -150px 0px 0px 70px
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <img src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/25/590x/Great-Pyramid-of-Giza-secret-mystery-energy-996924.jpg?r=1533059304339" width="100%" height="auto" alt="image">
  <P class="text1">This is a test text</p>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <P class="text1">This is a test text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Are you asking how to append an `img` element using jQuery, or set the `background-image` CSS rule?

Comment: _“This image has to be loaded behind the text.”_ - so simply a _background image_ then? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: what i mean is to load an image into div two with a script (css, javascript or jQuery ), and so that the text is in front of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the image element programmatically and insert it into the two element.

```js
// Create image element
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/25/590x/Great-Pyramid-of-Giza-secret-mystery-energy-996924.jpg?r=1533059304339');

// Insert it into the two element
const two = document.querySelector('#two');
two.insertBefore(img, two.firstChild);
```

```css
#one, #two {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <img src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/25/590x/Great-Pyramid-of-Giza-secret-mystery-energy-996924.jpg?r=1533059304339">
  <p class="text">This is a test text</p>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <p class="text">This is a test text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Dominic! This works well! And thanks for the extra control css!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.getElementById("two") // Get the div that You want to insert the image to
var img = document.createElement("img") // Create image element
// Set image source to url of a photo
img.src = "https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/25/590x/Great-Pyramid-of-Giza-secret-mystery-energy-996924.jpg?r=1533059304339"
// Set image width attribute
img.width = "100%"
// Set image height attribute
img.height = "auto"
// Set image alt attribute
img.alt = "image"
// Insert image into the div
div.insertBefore(img, div.firstChild)
```

This is how You append an image into div with id "two" before the text paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get your image in div#one
var img = document.querySelector('#one img');
// Get your div#two where to add the image
var two = document.querySelector('#two');

// Insert the img as 1st child of div#two
// Use cloneNode() to keep a copy in div#one
two.insertBefore(img.cloneNode(), two.firstChild);
```

```css
.text1 {
  margin: -150px 0px 0px 70px
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <img src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/25/590x/Great-Pyramid-of-Giza-secret-mystery-energy-996924.jpg?r=1533059304339" width="100%" height="auto" alt="image">
  <p class="text1">This is a test text</p>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <p class="text1">This is a test text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Armel. This works but does not place the text and image in correct position.

Answer (score 0):

You can create image tag give that image to source and append newly created image tag to div.

```js
var newimg = $('<img>');
var imgsrc = 'https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/25/590x/Great-Pyramid-of-Giza-secret-mystery-energy-996924.jpg?r=1533059304339'
newimg.attr('src', imgsrc);
newimg.appendTo('#two');
```

```css
.text1 {
  margin: -150px 0px 0px 70px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="two">
  <P class="text1">This is a test text</p>
</div>
```